# Could I do exclude with regex and sed a pattern which contains # before $ and possible blanks between?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm coding a bash script for a code migration project which contains three stages: parse, processing and fix. It uses sed with regex to parse a file which contains directives as shown:

```
$(first_directive)    : [                        \
     $(dependency) ] \
     $(another_dependency)  \
# several commands here
$(second_directive)    :   \
     $(more_dependencies)
# more commands here
```

Here the useful data for the process is only the strings $(first_directive) and $(second_directive), and I can recognize them because are the unique lines with colon after it. In order to parse these lines, I'm using in the script a command like this:

```
# Commands before
patterns=$(sed -nr "/\\$\(\w*\)\s*:/p" "${file}")
# More commands and processing after
```

That works fine, but I found that several lines are commented with # and I must discard them in the parse phase in order to avoid errors in the next stages of the process. Here is an example:

```
$(third_directive)    : [                        \
     $(dependency) ] \
# several commands here
#$(old_directive)    :   \  # I don't need this directive
#     $(old_dependencies)
### Commented code here
#  $(another_old_directive)   :   \ # I don't need this either
```

So, I'm searching for sed parameters or different regex which allows me to excluded the commented lines, but I've not succeeded yet. It's possible do it with only a command?

The following are some regex that I tested:

```
(?:[^\#]\s*)\$\(\w*\)\s*
.*[^#]\$\([A-Za-z]*\)\s*:
```

**Edit:** The # may not be at beginning of the line. In some cases, there are blanks before.

Comment: Would `grep -v` work for you? i.e. `patterns=$(sed -nr "/\\$\(\w*\)\s*:/p" "${file}" | grep -v "#")`

Comment: @jared_mamrot, It could work but also discards lines like `$(directive) : \ #comment`. I'm not 100% sure now if this situation ocurrs because I have a lot of directives files. I have to research it better, but it could maybe works fine.

Comment: Yep, @charlie_armstrong 's answer seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: @jared_mamrot, I tried to put a regex in the grep. I changed `grep -v "#"` by `grep -vE "\#\s*\\$"` and it works fine. It matches `$(directive) : \ #comment` and discards patterns like `#  $(directive)  :`

Comment: Nice - glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply exclude lines that start with #:

`^\s*[^#].*:.*\$\n`

Here `.*` can be replaced with any other conditions you may have.

Comment: Hi Charlie, welcome to Stack Overflow. That's a good proposal. I forget specify in the question that may be blanks before #. I've edited it with this information. It's possible adjust your regex to match this case too?

Comment: Thank you!  I just updated my answer to also check for whitespace.

Comment: I'd recommend to test your regex with the posted files.

Comment: I've tested it using PCRE.  Could you tell me what doesn't work for you?  Are you using a different regex flavor?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong your regex matches lines with or without `:`. Moreover `sed` does not support `PCRE`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I guess I was just thinking general regex, but you're right, that won't work in `sed`.  I've updated my answer to filter out lines with no `:` and I've added all the backslashes one needs in `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try:

```
sed -n '/^[^#]*\$.*:/p' "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\s*\$([^)]*)\s*:/p' file
```

See [demo](https://asciinema.org/a/VRDkEvdPSGXiW6aefCenkOED4).